# Better to call functions repeatedly or store function result in variable for reuse in plsql procedure

Tags: oracle, function, variables, plsql

Is it best practice / more efficient to call a defined function several times within a procedure or to store the function result in a local variable and use the held variable value instead?

The value returned from within the function is a date value.
(select start_date from extract_dates)

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a good idea to call the function once and reuse the returned value many times if possible - e.g. when looping:

```
declare
  l_start_date date;
begin
  l_start_date := get_start_date_for_dept (10);
  for r in (select id from big_table) loop
    process_record (r.id, l_start_date );
  end loop;
end;
```

Here the function is called once rather than as many times as `big_table` has rows.  If each call takes a millisecond, and `big_table` has 10,000 rows then calling the function inside the loop could add 10 seconds to the overall run-time.  This is just standard programming good practice.

Comment: Also worth remembering that the deterministic and result cache features of functions can have a big effect on performance when used in appropriate circumstances.